# Combine each of the values from one array with each of the values in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there anything that can take two arrays and combine each of their respective values? And the arrays are not the same length.  Like this:

```js
array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
array2 = ["twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty"]

arrayWant= ["twentyone", "twentytwo", "twentythree", "thirtyone", "thirtytwo", "thirtythree", "fortyone", "fortytwo", "fortythree"...]
```

Comment: Not sure how `explode` factors into this at all…!?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201141/discussion-on-question-by-katie-neeley-is-there-anything-in-javascript-like-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no equivalent in `javascript` afaict. But you can write yourself.

```js
let array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
let array2 = ["twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty"]

let arrayWant= array2.map(x=>array1.map(y=>x+y)).flat()

console.log(arrayWant)
```

---

also, `Array.forEach` would return `undefined`, so you should use `map` for this.

Comment: Thank you! There are quite a few things here I need to research but this is doing exactly what I need. Thank you so much!